# Convert a textbox string to javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a textbox that contains the following -

> [[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 1], [6, 6]]

I need to be able to convert this to an array, in exactly the same format for a graph. The code I have tried below does not work as it does not have the square brackets inside the array.

```
/*****SIMPLE CHART*****/
        var flashstring = document.getElementsByName('hfMessageHistory')[0].value;

        var flash = new Array();
        flash = flashstring.split(",");

        for (a in flash) {
            flash[a] = parseInt(flash[a], 10) || 0; // Explicitly include base as per Álvaro's comment
        }

        alert(flash);

        function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
            jQuery('<div id="tooltip" class="tooltipflot">' + contents + '</div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'none',
                top: y + 5,
                left: x + 5
            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
        }


        var plot = jQuery.plot(jQuery("#chartplace"),
               [{ data: [flash], label: "Messages Sent", color: "#ff6c00" }], {
                   series: {
                       lines: { show: true, fill: true, fillColor: { colors: [{ opacity: 0.05 }, { opacity: 0.15 }] } },
                       points: { show: true }
                   },
                   legend: { position: 'nw' },
                   grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true, borderColor: '#ccc', borderWidth: 1, labelMargin: 10 },
                   yaxis: { min: 0, max: 20 }
               });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is JSON. Use JSON.parse():

```
var flashstring = document.getElementsByName('hfMessageHistory')[0].value;
var flash = JSON.parse(flashstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding other parts of your code(not clear what you're asking), you can covert a string to an array by using the bracket([]):

```
var str = '[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 1], [6, 6]]'
var arr = [str];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="text1" />
<button onclick="parse()">Parse</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#text1').val('[[0, 0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0], [5, 1], [6, 6]]');

function parse() {
    try {
        var parsed = JSON.parse($('#text1').val());
        console.log(parsed);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('parse failed. Check your input');
    }
 }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z9s92rgq/).